# Best way to check a setting in all profiles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-profiles

Using ASP.net, is there a recommended best way to access a particular field of the profile in code. I was looking in my old Problem-Design-Solution 2.0 book, and it does it by pulling all members in the DB and then iterating through each one's profile (see code below). Is there a better way?

```
for each (MembershipUser user in Membership.GetAllUsers())
{
    ProfileCommon userProfile = profile.GetProfile(user.UserName);
    if (userProfile.mysetting == desiredValue)
    { 
         //do something
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

I found that it can be done a little more efficiently than pulling members and then pulling profiles. It is possible that not all members have a profile, so if you use the following code, you'll pull all the profiles (which may be fewer in number than members, and then can iterate across it:

```
for each (ProfileInfo theProfile in ProfileManager.GetAllProfiles (ProfileAuthenticationOption.All)
{
    ProfileCommon pc = ProfileBase.Create(theProfile.UserName)
    if (pc.mysetting == desiredValue)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

It still round trips the DB for each profile, but it may not do it as many as if we used the members...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With built-in Profiles, no there isn't a better way. One option as provided by Tim is Table Profile provider or writing your own profile provider.

Or you can go completely other route i.e. [storing profile information](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-cs) in your own custom table.

Comment: I've heard of the table profile provider that's mentioned, but our site will be small enough it isn't a huge deal. I was just wondering if there was a better way to do it.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do better with linq, I don't have VS with me right now, but pseudo code would look something like this:

```
var users = from MembershipUser user in Membership.GetAllUsers()
  where user.mysetting == desiredValue
  select user
```

then iterate over the users,

```
foreach(MembershipUser u in users) {
// do something
}
```

that should only contain the ones of interest.  Linq should handle executing the SQL for you correctly, but you can check to see what it's doing with profiler.

---

**EDIT**

Actually that probably won't get you anything from a performance perspective, the GetAllUsers is going to bring back everything.  You might want to create a linq2sql dbml map for the users table and use that instead of Membership class for querying against a custom property.

---

**EDIT 2**

[ASP.NET Roles and Profiles: best way to query for collection of users who match custom profile property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019725/asp-net-roles-and-profiles-best-way-to-query-for-collection-of-users-who-match-c)

If you're using the table profile provider you may be able to use the linq query against that table:
http://weblogs.asp.net/kencox/archive/2010/09/05/using-the-sql-table-profile-provider-in-asp-net-4-web-applications-c-amp-vb.aspx

Comment: I guess I'm kind of confused, the MembershipUser object wouldn't contain anything from the profile so pulling it via Linq doesn't help wtih the profile information.

Comment: That's why I mentioned the table profile in Edit 2, you would want to write the linq query against that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Table Profile Provider](http://www.asp.net/downloads/sandbox/table-profile-provider-samples) and build custom queries to get your desired settings.